# Format date using variable

Tags: c#, date-format

Following gives output as 20121212.

```
DateTime dd = new DateTime(2012, 12, 12);
string val = String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}", dd);
```

And when the format is in a variable. Following does not give above output.

```
DateTime dd = new DateTime(2012, 12, 12);
string dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd";
string val = String.Format("{0}:{1}", dd, dateFormat);
```

How can can I achieve it using format in a variable as above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `DateTime.ToString`:

```
string val = dd.ToString( dateFormat );
```

You are confusing `String.Format` with your format string which does work only in this way `{0:yyyyMMdd}`.

Comment: @eMi: No, a `DateTime?` is not a `DateTime`. You have to use `nullableDateTime.Value.ToString("...")` or better, using the new null-conditional-operator: `nullableDateTime?.ToString("...");`

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have the format in a string variable, May this is what you are looking for:

```
DateTime dd = new DateTime(2012, 12, 12);
string strFormat = "yyyyMMdd";
string val = String.Format("{0:"+ strFormat + "}", dd);
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would just be

```
DateTime dd = new DateTime(2012, 12, 12);
string strFormat = "yyyyMMdd";
string val = dd.ToString(strFormat);
```

`String.Format` doesn't directly support variable format strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DateTime.ToString(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method :

```
DateTime dd = new DateTime(2012, 12, 12);
string dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd";
string val = dd.ToString(dateFormat);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) like this;

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2012, 12, 12);
string Format = "yyyyMMdd";
string yourstring = String.Format("{0:" + Format + "}", dt);
Console.WriteLine(yourstring);
```

[`Demo`](http://ideone.com/Q2zI7n)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use .ToString(string format)

```
DateTime dd = new DateTime(2012, 12, 12);
string strFormat = "yyyyMMdd";
string val = dd.ToString(strFormat);
```